# How to control fan speed on Acer V3-571G

Tags: speed, fan, acer-aspire

Speed fan, Gpu Tweaker any many more do not detect any fans on my laptop. **How can I gain control above them?** My computer is getting warm really fast and I would like to do something about that.

Acer V3-571g
i3-3110
GeForce GT630
Full specs: http://wklej.org/id/900178/

EDIT:
Fans are quiet now, but when I go into the game they go fast. I am not sure that I did not screw up fan settings earlier, but I do not know what programm I usedThe issue is that when I play for example Dirt 3 after one race computer is heating to much so  or even menu starts to go low on fps(like 15, and on cool 30-35->I checcekd it outside on cold wheather everything worked smooth all the time). The BIOS does not have these settings, unfortunatelly there is not much to do in this version of BIOS. I would like to speed up the fan. This is new computer(1.5 months now) but it got worse in a day.

Answer (score 1):

Are the fans running on high now?   Most laptops do a decent job of running the fans fast when they are warm,  most users use a Fan utility to SLOW the fans to reduce noise.
If your laptop is warmer than it used to be,  I'd check that the vents are clean.  I've seen more overheating laptops that were due to dirt on the heatsink or clogged vents than I have due to a bad sensor that failed to turn the fans on.

Comment: In addition, @Robert can check the BIOS to verify the settings.  Many have a "Cool and Quiet" type setting, where if there are heating issues - you may need to change it to Performance or whatever.  If the option exists, that is.

Comment: Fans are quiet now, but when I go into the game they go fast. I am not sure that I did not screw up fan settings earlier, but I do not know what programm I usedThe issue is that when I play for example Dirt 3 after one race computer is heating to much so  or even menu starts to go low on fps(like 15, and on cool 30-35->I checcekd it outside on cold wheather everything worked smooth all the time). The BIOS does not have these settings, unfortunatelly there is not much to do in this version of BIOS. I would like to speed up the fan. This is new computer(1.5 months now) but it got worse in a day.